# How can I average multiple outputs independently in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, average

PYTHON 3:    Hi, so I have this piece of code

```
for money in range(0, 2501, 500):
    print("{} Euro".format(money), end='')
    throws = 0
    d = trump.possession(board)

    while False in d.values():
        prevLoc = piece.location
        piece.move(trump.throw())
        throws += 1
        if piece.location < prevLoc:
            money += 200

        if board.names[piece.location] in d and d[board.names[piece.location]] == False and money >= board.values[piece.location]:
            money -= board.values[piece.location]
            d[board.names[piece.location]] = True
    return throws
```

and this code takes 0 money to start with, runs the code, looks for amount of throws required to buy the entire board, does the same with 500 starting money, 1000 and so forth

my question is, how can i take the average of the throws to buy the entire board for each starting value? the way my code is now it returns the amount of throws for all the starting values, but simulated once, so it may not be accurate.
I searched a lot, and tried some things but i had problems with this one because I want to like run it, say for example, 2000 times, and get the average for each starting value for the money.

anyone got any tips for this? been struggling on it for a while..

i tried making a for loop from 0 to 2000 and then inside of that another for loop that prints 0-2500 and then uses the code below in a function, appends the return value of throws into a list and sums it up and devides it by 2000, it did not turn out so good...

Comment: What does your data look like? What is the expected output, you can spare the explanation if you just present those simple facts `input`, `output`

Comment: yes, i'm sorry :(

Comment: expected output: 0 Euro, _ throws, 500 Euro _ throws, 1000 Euro _ throws, 1500 Euro _ throws, 2000 Euro _ throws, 2500 Euro _ throws

Comment: im getting the amount of throws but thats for running my code once, i want to run my code like 2000 times and  get the average amount of throws for each of the euros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is in a function, due to the return statement.  You need to collect outputs into a list and then average that at the end.

```
def calc_throws(simulations):
    throw_list = []
    average = lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)
    for i, money in enumerate(range(0, 2501, 500)):
        print("{} Euro".format(money), end='')
        throw_list.append([money, []])
        for _ in range(simulations):
            throws = 0
            d = trump.possession(board)
            while False in d.values():
                prevLoc = piece.location
                piece.move(trump.throw())
                throws += 1
                if piece.location < prevLoc:
                    money += 200

                if board.names[piece.location] in d and d[board.names[piece.location]] == False and money >= board.values[piece.location]:
                    money -= board.values[piece.location]
                    d[board.names[piece.location]] = True
            throw_list[i][1].append(throws)
        throw_list[i][1] = average(throw_list[i][1])
    return throw_list
```

Rather than a single number, this returns a list of lists like `#[[0,20],[500,15],...[2500,3]]` (or whatever reasonable numbers are) which gives you the average for each amount of starting money.

Comment: hey man, thank you so much, but would you know how i can print it seperately, like 0 Euro: x steps 'newline' 500 Euro: x steps 'newline' and so forth

Comment: because i made a new main function right now and tried to print this function but it gave nothing

Comment: Need to return throw_list instead of throws, I will fix it.